# Disable WAL in influxdb v0.13 or force flush

Tags: influxdb, wal

I am trying to setup a simple cluster for influxdb on AWS using EFS (elastic file storage which is similar to NFS) where 2 different influx processes will share database.
I have 2 EC2 instances (named: EC2_1, EC2_2) running their own influxdb processes.
Both EC2 instances are mounted with a common EFS directory called "efs" at /opt/efs.
I modified influxdb.conf on both ec2 instances to have it point to common **/opt/efs/influxdb/data** directory for data, **/opt/efs/influxdb/wal** for wal,**/opt/efs/influxdb/meta** for meta directories.

What I am trying to achieve by this is when EC2_1 influx process writes something to database it can be immediately read by influx process on EC2_2.

To achieve this I am trying to find out a setting that can disable WAL or make writing to disk very frequent (once/sec) so that another process can read directly from disk. Read/Write performance or data loss is not a major concern for me right now.

I tried changing below setting hoping that it will make WAL flush frequent but it did not work the way I expected:

```
# CacheSnapshotMemorySize is the size at which the engine will
# snapshot the cache and write it to a TSM file, freeing up memory
# cache-snapshot-memory-size = 26214400
  cache-snapshot-memory-size = 2

# CacheSnapshotWriteColdDuration is the length of time at
# which the engine will snapshot the cache and write it to
# a new TSM file if the shard hasn't received writes or deletes
# cache-snapshot-write-cold-duration = "1h"
  cache-snapshot-write-cold-duration = "1s"
```

If EC2_1 writes something to influxdb, querying EC2_2 does not show that data unless influxdb process on EC2_2 is restarted and vice versa.

Comment: Can you add a bit more detail about your use case?

Comment: Edited my original question @MichaelDesa

Comment: I see.  I'd open a [feature request](https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb/issues/new) on the InfluxDB repo asking for this functionality. I feel like there used to be a way to control WAL flushes, but I'm not sure if thats still the case. Whats the reason you want to have two instances writing and reading from the same disk?

Comment: Thanks, I will request it on github. I am trying to achieve a customized clustering where EFS snapshots are taken by lambda functions in AWS and I dont have to rely on influxdb replication.

Comment: I see. Running multiple InfluxDB instances on the same file system will lead to data corruption.

Answer (score 0):

So there's not a way to disable the WAL entirely or to make it flush every second.